# How should I handle anonymous user input?

Tags: python, django, facebook, user-input, anonymous

I'd like the users of my web application to not have to register a user account before they can vote. I've seen websites where I could freely vote up or down on what ever I want without having to register. How is this handled? How can I prevent the same person from voting infinite amounts of times?

I'm using Python and Django. I'm thinking of implementing facebook login, but I'd like to hear some of the experts' comments. I'll mark the most helpful answer as correct.

Comment: im not familiar with django, but suggesting to just keep track of IPs, and allow one vote for each IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on facebook login, as users without facebook will not be able to vote.

As there is no real way to be sure that an unregistered user will not vote twice (he can connect himself from another computer, or whatever), you have to define yourself what is the criteria you want to use to check his identity.

You have different ways to solve your problem, all of them rely on storing information about the user that voted. You can rely on ip address, or store information in session or in cookies to know if your users already voted or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a session variable that will tell me whether they've voted or not. True, the user could clear their cookies and vote twice but that is an edge case. If you're letting them vote without registering I'm guessing the poll isn't too scientific.

Django has some good examples on their website about how to use sessions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#examples

This one in particular should be helpful to you. Instead of votes they're dealing with comments:

```
def post_comment(request, new_comment):
    if request.session.get('has_commented', False):
        return HttpResponse("You've already commented.")
    c = comments.Comment(comment=new_comment)
    c.save()
    request.session['has_commented'] = True
    return HttpResponse('Thanks for your comment!')
```